# Stop Safari from submitting form based on required fields

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, validation, safari

I am trying to prevent my form from submitting in Safari, when a required field has not been filled out. I have looked at a few different answers on here, but they still let my form submit. Currently I have it flagging the required fields correctly but it still allows submission.

```
$('#qtrAuditform').on('submit',function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var $form = $(this),
   data = $form.serialize();
   var url = 'http://localhost:8888/datatest';
     $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: url,
     data: data,
     success: function(){
        alert('Your form has been successfully submitted!');
    },
    fail:function(){
        alert('something went wrong...try again');
    }
});
});
```

I just want something simple that works. Please advise

Comment: Please provide [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Comment: you have given function for submitting the form..where is your function for validating the form?

Comment: If you put `required` in the attributes of the elements, the browser will do this automatically.

Comment: I used this to validate the fields, downloaded it from github. http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/07/27/creating-cross-browser-html5-forms-now-using-modernizr-webforms2-and-html5widgets-2/